# Spark scala join two dataframes on columns with different name

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm trying to join two dataframes on a column with two different names :

```
   def joinTwoDataframes(X:DataFrame)(Y:DataFrame): DataFrame = {
     X.join(Y,X("ssp") === Y("impbus_ssp_value")) }
```

The error is: "Cannot resolve column name "ssp" among (impbus_ssp_value, col2);"

Thanks!

Comment: X does not have the column `ssp`. Check the column names.

Comment: How can a column have two names? I think mck is right, you might be swapping the dataframes or the column names

Comment: yeah I changed the name of the column and it worked thanks !